# jquery click event priority over inline click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<span class='click2' onclick="ClickBack();">Click me </span>

</body>
<script>

$(".click2").click(function (event) {
    if(confirm("Sure to continue"))
    event.stopImediatePropagation();
});
function ClickBack() {
    alert('yes I am click1');
}
</script>
</html>
```

My requirement is to call `ClickBack()` only when its being confirmed by , and i cannot make any change in **ClickBack**  function , Its ony one case,

main thing is

**I have to add this click2 to a number of elements, and it will basically call the inline events only after confirmation** by click2

**$(".click2").click(function (event)**

I am getting two issue,

- **ClickBack is being fired firstly,**
- **TypeError: event.stopImediatePropagation is not a function** it was type mistake thanks to @manwal its solved

**How can I achieve my goal.
I cannot make any change in ClickBack()  function**

Please advise

Thanks

Comment: use this - `event.stopPropagation();` instead of `event.stopImediatePropagation();`

Comment: why not call ClickBack() inside $(".click2").click(function (event) {.

Comment: Just a note: always add your `script` tag above the `</body>` tag. :)

Comment: @Glizzweb stopPropagation not working'

Answer (score 2):

You have typo issue, use this line there should be double `m`:

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation()
```

instead of

```
event.stopImediatePropagation()
           ^
```

Comment: So what is another @Md.ParvezAlam?

Comment: It is mentioned in question

Answer (score 0):

for this *ClickBack is being fired firstly,* problem the solution is remove `onclick="ClickBack();"` from

```
<span class='click2' onclick="ClickBack();">Click me </span>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it look likes, not a solution but erasing problem

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam If you do not want ClickBack() to be called then dont  call it

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you bind `inline` `onclick` function it will be trigerred first.
So instead of adding it `inline` do it in your `script` like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <span class='click2'>Click me </span>FD
    <script>

        $(".click2").click(function (event) {
            if (confirm("Sure to call ClickBack"))
            {
                ClickBack();
            }
        });
        function ClickBack() {
            alert('yes I am click1');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **I have to add this click2 to a number of elements, and it will basically call the events written before only after confirmation**

Comment: Can you elaborate your requirement ?

Comment: Please go through question, I thinks its pretty clear

Comment: you asked to call `clickback()` after confirmation from user. And you can achieve it from the code given.

Comment: I have to add this click2 to a number of elements, and it will basically call the events written before only after confirmation

Comment: so u can use `callback`. Pass your function name as param and call it in your function after confirmation.
Like this:

`function click2(callback){if (confirm("Sure to call ClickBack"))callback();}`

Now bind this function with your elements and pass the function name as `parameter` of your function.

Comment: Thanks for taking pain, But click2 function is common over other elements, which will be called before it's inline function will be called

Answer (score 0):

Remove `onclick` event handler from `span`

`<span class='click2'>Click me </span>`

and call the `ClickBack` function in on click event handler for `.click2` class as follows,

```
<script>

$(".click2").click(function (event) {
    if(confirm("Sure to call ClickBack"))
    ClickBack();
});
function ClickBack() {
    alert('yes I am click1');
}

</script>
```

Comment: There are lots of function , so i cannot call all of them

Comment: **I have to add this click2 to a number of elements, and it will basically call the events written before only after confirmation**

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span class='click2'>Click me </span>FD
<script>
    $(".click2").click(function (event) {
        if (confirm("Sure to call ClickBack"))
        {
            ClickBack();
        }
    });
    function ClickBack() {
        alert('yes I am click1');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and my question, both look similar

Comment: i have made some changes found error here`event.stopImmediatePropagation()` and added `<script>` tag inside `<body>` tag

Comment: that error has already been replicated and mentioned in question

Comment: have you tried code answered what error you find in my code

Comment: Yes, and its the same output, inline function getting invoked first

Comment: what about now made some changes